# How can I make my div spawn within 400 px of either side using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making an animated background for a webpage that spawn div elements to look like bubbles and animates their transparency. I want the bubbles to only spawn within the left 400px and the right 400px of the screen. I can get them to spawn in the middle, but when I try to make it spawn on the edges it breaks the code. (maybe an infinite loop?)

```
function bubble() {
  var rightOffset = $(window).width() - 400; //where i want them on the right

  do {
    var leftPx = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width() - 100);
  } while (leftPx >= 400 || rightOffset <= leftPx);

  var topPx = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height() - 100); //not even going to worry about the top yet

  if(bubbleCount <= 30){
    bubbleCount ++;
    $('html').append("<div class=bubble style=' left: " + leftPx + "px; top: " + topPx + "px;'></div>");
    $('.bubble').animate({
      opacity: 0.5,
    }, 3000, 'swing')
    .animate({
      opacity: 0,
    }, 3000, 'swing', function(){
      $(this).remove();
      bubbleCount -= 1;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply randomize the side as well? This way you don't have to check and discard potential positions. Something like this.

```
function randomBetween(min,max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

var width = $(window).width();
var leftPixels = Math.round(Math.random()) ? randomBetween(0, 400) :
                 randomBetween(width - 400, width);
```

What happens here is that it first randomly generates 0 or 1, and then if it's 1 it generates a LEFT side value and if 0 generates a RIGHT side value. No extra iterations that slow down your program.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your [***bubble effect***](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/qt0owuLn/1/) and didn't end up with a break in code!

I think what you are missing is that for an *absolute-positioned bubble* to be positioned from right, you need to give it a `right` CSS offset value; likewise, for a left absolute-positioned bubble, stick to the `left` property:

```
var rightOffset = $(window).width() - 400; //where i want them on the right
do {
  var rightPx = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width() - 100);
} while (rightPx >= 400 || rightOffset <= rightPx);

/*
* ...
*/
$('html').append("<div class='bubble' style=' right: " + rightPx + "px; top: " + topPx + "px;'></div>");
```